# What happen under the hood in javascript if function is having more than one return Statment?

Tags: javascript, function

In the below code I want to know what is going under the hood?

```js
function data() {
  return 4;
  return;
}

console.log(data()); // return 4
```

But

```js
function data() {
  return;
  return 4;
}
console.log(data()); //return undefined
```

What is the reason behind this? I might think that reason behind it is "javascript is an interpreted language" but I am not sure.

Comment: Only the first return statement in a block gets executed everything after it is not executed.

Comment: Do you understand what `return` does?  And why that means the second one gets ignored?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#description: _“When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller.”_

Comment: Yaa, I am very well aware what return does.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with the language being interpreted.

Comment: so you are saying function return when it encounter first return statment?

Comment: Ok I got it =. Thanks...

Comment: @ujjwal_bansal yes. That is what is meant by _"When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped."_

Comment: I don't think "very well aware" means what you think it means.

Comment: [return statment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) read more about return, also go through this [medium article](https://medium.com/@gaurav.pandvia/understanding-javascript-function-executions-tasks-event-loop-call-stack-more-part-1-5683dea1f5ec)

Comment: @ScottHunter "you keep using that word".

Comment: Ok Thanks everyone on comments I got my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will return on the first `return`.

```js
function data(){
       return ;
       return 4;
    }
console.log(data());
```

In above code with first `return` you are not returning any param/value so it remains undefined.